# Tab order in radio buttons is not working

Tags: html, jsf-2, radio-button, tabindex

Can any one tell me how to specify tab order in JSF2.0 Moajarra? I'm having a text box (`h:inputText`) and a radio button (`h:selectOneRadio`) (shows `Yes` and `No`) and a drop down (`h:selectOneMenu`) in my page. 
Once I press tab from text box, it is going to `Yes` radio option and then once again if I press tab from `Yes` radio option it is going to drop down which I'm expecting it to be at `No` radio option. Can any one suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's expected behavior when radio buttons belong to the same group (read: when they have the same `name` and you can select only one of them). You're in such case supposed to use the arrow keys to switch between radio buttons in the same group.

Note that this all has nothing to do with JSF. This is specific to HTML and you would have exactly the same problem when having a "plain vanilla" HTML page with the same HTML representation as generated by JSF (and even when usign a different server side language which also generates HTML, such as PHP/ASP/etc). Note that every website works that way and thus endusers should already be used to that behavior.

#### See also:

- [W3C wiki - radio buttons](http://www.w3.org/wiki/RadioButton) - check section "Keyboard interaction"

Comment: Ok thanks. But do we have attribute like 'tabOrder' for ALL our JSF2.0 components (inputText, selectOneMenu etc)?

Comment: It's just the same as in HTML: `tabindex`. Are you new to HTML as well or so? In any case, you can just find an overview of all tags and attributes in VDL documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/

Comment: I should have applied my brain before asking. Apologies. Any way I got a nice link from you. Thanks.